# Working on a subproject without first opening it

Tags: vsto, ms-office, ms-project

I have a ".mpp" file that has a master project and sub-projects. I want to be able to modify and read the sub-projects, without having to call "FileOpen" for each sub-project.

I see that `Globals.ThisAddin.Application.ActiveProject` has a `SubProjects` collection, but each element seems to be of type sub-project.

The problem with `FileOpen` is that it visually pops up a new instance of Microsoft Project.

Basically, is it possible to call `FileOpen` (*or any other similar method*) without visually showing a new instance of Microsoft Project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution (but it only works for Office 2010 and above).

Basically, Globals.ThisAddin.Application.Subprojects[index].SourceProject, will return a reference to the subproject which you can work with like a normal project.